# CrudRepostiroy findBy query/method to fetch records based on Raw Type value which is a ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, sql, jpa, types, raw

Can someone please advice how to filter records based on a raw data column value in JPA ?

I have entity class as below :

```
@Entity
public class TableAbc {
    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;
    private String fieldA;
    private ArrayList<String> listA;
    ...
```

Above `listA` is a raw type column at DB level which I can't change. Here save works fine, `findById`/`findByFieldA` works fine, `findAll` works fine.

However `findByListA` would not work as shown below. It throws class cast exception. Here all is strictly typed so no other laps. `listA` which is passed to `findByListA` is correct I assure. Any solution or alternative would be helpful. Return value should be List of `TableAbc`.

```
public interface TableAbcRepository extends CrudRepository<TableAbc, UUID> {
  List<TableAbc> findByFieldA(String fieldA); // This works
  List<TableAbc> findByListA(ArrayList<String> listA); // This does not work
}
```

Comment: How ist listA mapped to the database? What database are you using and what is the colum type of listA?

Comment: column type of listA is raw type at DB level (not varchar2). Database is in memory hsql DB. It store data as object byte string. It is like xxxjava.util.ArrayListxxxxxxabc10001xx. Here x could be some special characters.